# Refresh outer nav when variable changes - Angular

Tags: angularjs

In my index.html file I have site navigation. This is my main angular page for a SPA. The navigation changes on whether a user is logged in or not. I set a cookie when a user logs in and a variable is set in the scope named `cookieSet`. This is an ajax call so no page refresh

Is it possible to refresh the HTML run by the controller when that variable changes?

Here's what I do:

```
// set the variable
capApp.controller('cookieCtrl', ['$scope','$cookies', function($scope, $cookies) {
  // set variable for nav
  $scope.cookieSet = $cookies.user_id;
}]);
```

HTML within index.html page:

```
<div id="siteNav" ng-controller="cookieCtrl">
  <nav class="className" role="navigation" ng-show="!cookieSet">
    <!-- NO cookieSet variable, show this -->
  </nav>
  <nav class="className" role="navigation" ng-show="cookieSet">
    <!-- cookieSet variable IS SET, show this -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

When a user logs out, the cookie is killed and I do a page refresh, it's when a user logs in and the cookie is set, therefore the `cookieSet` variable changes that I need to watch for then refresh the navigation - is this possible?

Comment: When a user logs out, set the `$cookieSet` to `null` - it should trip a `$digest` cycle and refresh the view.

Comment: Its not a view though, its the actual outer html that the views are injected into the middle of `<body><nav>...HERE...</nav><div ng-view></div></body>`

Comment: As long as it's within the scope of the controller, the ng-show (and other bindings) will be re-evaluated, so tymeJV's solution should work. I personally just hooked up the authentication controller (cookieCtrl in your case) to the main container or even body, so user info bindings are available everywhere.